# Object.Freeze Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How can I give an Object.Freeze on just one object?

Here's the example below where I create `a`, I replicate `a` in `b`, freeze the `b`, and try to re-assign a value to `a`. But it is no longer possible. Why? How do I do `freeze` on just one object?

Thank you!

```js
let a = { "teste" : [1,2,3] }

// I want 'b' freezed
const b = a;
Object.freeze(b);

a.teste = [4,5,6]

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Your code here only involves one object. If you freeze it, it will be frozen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you're misunderstanding the concept of references in javascript.
Objects are referenced in javascript, so when you do

```
const b = a;
```

basically you are assigning `b` a value of the reference `a`, in order to get your code to work, and actually "replicate" like you intend, you need to clone the object not pass a reference.

You can use `Object.assign({}, ...)` to clone an object into a new one. *(notice that its not deep cloning but it should get you going)*

```js
let a = { "teste" : [1,2,3] }

// I want 'b' freezed
const b = Object.assign({}, a);
Object.freeze(b);

a.teste = [4,5,6]

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Nice answer. You can also use spread operator for this `const b = {...a};`

Comment: true! thanks for highlighting that

Comment: Note that object spread is currently a [Stage 3 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-rest-spread), and not yet part of any ECMAScript standard.

Comment: Thanks a looooot man, you save my life!!!

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Javascript are passed by reference, so in your example, the variables `a` and `b` refer to the same object. `Object.freeze` works on the object itself, not the reference, so there's no difference whether you refer to it using `a` or `b`. This is the same as if you'd just set a property:

```
let a = { "test" : [1,2,3] }
const b = a;
b.test = [4,5,6]
console.log(a)
```

If you want to freeze or modify `b` without affecting `a`, you'll need to clone it first. One way of doing this is using `Object.assign`:

```
let a = { "test" : [1,2,3] }

const b = Object.assign({}, a);
Object.freeze(b);
a.test = [4,5,6]

console.log(a)
```

This works by copying all of `a`'s properties to an empty object, then assigning that to `b`.

Comment: Got it ! Thanks a loot man :)